# Looking for a $2^9 \times 3^4$ design / orthogonal array

Tags: experiment-design

I need to find a design that would deal with nine factors with two levels, and four factors with three levels. To be precise, I need an orthogonal array balanced on the second order (i.e., all pairwise combinations of factors are present in the array the same number of times), but it seems to me it is easier to find the designs than the orthogonal arrays.

I have a working knowledge of Hadamard matrices, if that helps.

As I am reasonably expecting the design to have 432 or 576 runs or so, I would be happy to have an algorithm to expand a smaller design to the size that I need.

Answer (score 2):

I guess some Googling would not have hurt. Neil Sloane of AT&T has a variety of orthogonal arrays on his page here: http://neilsloane.com/oadir/. Anything from the list of arrays with 36 or 72 runs that has $2^m 3^n$ in the title of the arrays works for my purposes. One example is $6^1 3^8 2^{10}$, from which I just need to cut the middle part. No need to go for 576 runs!

```
0 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
0 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
4 1 2 1 2 2 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
5 1 2 1 2 0 2 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
5 2 1 2 1 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
4 2 1 2 1 0 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
2 1 2 2 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
3 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
3 2 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
2 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
2 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
3 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 2 0 2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
4 2 0 0 2 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
5 2 0 0 2 2 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
5 0 2 2 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
4 0 2 2 0 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
4 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
5 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
4 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
2 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
3 0 1 0 1 2 1 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
3 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
2 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 2 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```